# The Music Grunniens

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, music

[image: The Music Grunniens]

Clues:

[Contextual image: music notes, two +1 markings]

Instructions:

Name that actor

_ _ _ _ _ _ C _ _ _ _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing actor is

> HUGH JACKMAN

Let's take the notes on the staff,

> convert them to numbers (A=1, etc.), and sum them together when connected by a bar:
>  D+D=4+4=8=H
>  G+G+G=7+7+7=21=U
>  G
>  E
>  Ex5=5x5=25=Y
>  A
>  E+E+1=5+5+1=11=K
>  F+F+1=6+6+1=13=M
>  A
>  Bx7=2x7=14=N

Which gives

> "Huge Yakman" which might be [mistaken](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/356910339213164417/) for our answer which fits the provided blanks: Hugh Jackman!

As for the title,

> "Grunniens" is the scientific name for a yak.

> OP Addition - In 2021 Hugh Jackman played Harold Hill in The Music Man.